# How to become a good database designer?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I learned basic mysql from some books and w3school. I want to know how to increase my knowledge on database design for developing higher level application for future projects.

Thanks 
Alamgir

Comment: All questions like "how do I become good at ..." can be answered with "practice, practice, practice". Same applies here. What answer were you expecting? Drink this and boom, you're an expert?

Comment: To echo fancyPants's Comment, I suggest coming back to us when you have built _and used_ 5 databases.  Ideas: expenses, photos, friends, student-class-classroom-teacher, and others.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with fancyPants's Comment.

**short answer**: practice, practice, practice

but **Long Answer**: (in theory of Data Modeling)

every techniques and frameworks in computer science have some patterns. Database Design for Information Systems or Data Modeling has some patterns too.

I recommend following steps to learn data modeling patterns (I've been teaching them for 6 years):

Introduction to Data Modeling Heuristics and Patterns 
Data Modeling Patterns – Entity, Attributes 
Data Modeling Patterns – Relationships, Cardinality 
Types of Attributes (Composite, Multi-Value, Derived) 
Data Modeling Patterns – Trees and Graphs 
Data Modeling Patterns – Traps 
Data Modeling Patterns – List Pattern 
Data Modeling Patterns – Status Pattern 
Mapping Object Oriented Design to Relational Data Model

to find references, just google them or: 
Best collection of Data Modeling patterns, gathered in remarkable book:
 PATTERNS OF DATA MODELING, by MICHAEL BLAHA, CRC Press, (2010)