# E-R Diagram and Relational Tables

Tags: sql, database, relational-database, schema, entity-relationship

I need to use this description to make an E-R Diagram and then reduce it to relational tables. Later a creation of the tables is needed in SQL, but first I want to get these correct.

Consider the following set of requirements for a FAST FOOD CHAIN application.
This fast food chain can have several restaurants. Each restaurant has a manager and an
assistant manager (different from the manager), and several other employees like
cashiers, and cleaning personnel. We know the name, address, phone and salary of all
employees. Each restaurant keeps track of its inventory, so it knows how many items of each
item there are at the store. Each item has a provider with a name, and an address.
Customers visit restaurants to get food (items). There are two types of customers: regulars and VIP
customers. The fast food chain keeps track of the name, address, phone of each customer. For
VIP customers, however, the store also keeps track of the customer’s birthdate. The store keeps
track of each purchase made by a customer, by recording the date of purchase, the total
amount paid for the visit, and listing all the items purchased by the customer. Each purchase is made by a customer, and associated with the cashier.

My first attempt at the E-R Diagram is this:

[image]

My attempt at the tables look like:

```
Restaurant(manager, assistant_manager)

Employees(id, name, address, phone, salary)

Items(item_id, provider, address)

Customer(customer_id, type, name, address, phone, VIP)

Purchases(customer_id, cashier_id, total_paid, date_bought, items_bought)
```

Any help is appreciated! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You have many mistakes in you ER. 
**First of all**: It's better to read a Data Modeling Book in-depth.
see: [How to become a good database designer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47069979/how-to-become-a-good-database-designer/47444920#47444920)

I list some important mistakes:

1. Manager and Assistant Manager can not be attributes. They are types of Employees. You can have one-to-one relationship (with the name of Manager or Assistant_Manager) between Restaurant and Employees (For each of them : manager and assistant manager).
2. Based on your explains, it's better to have a Employee Type entity.
3. Provider of Items can turn into an Entity.
4. You should put purchases_id into Items.
5. Relationship between Purchases and Employees should be many-to-one (each Employee can handle many Purchases and each Purchase handled by one Employee).

Absolutely, each Employee can handle only one Purchase at the time. But when we designing ER, we should consider period of time instead of at the time. (for example: each Employee handles many Purchases in one day)